# Matching Every Nth Element of A Dataframe

Tags: r, gsub, grepl

I have what is probably a really dumb `grepl` in R question. Apologies, because this seems like it should be so easy - I'm obviously just missing something.

I have a character data.frame, let's call it `test`. Some of `test` is printed out below:

```
    userid  st_dt_tm           ctnid
PULCHNT     11/1/2017 16:54   503050724908.00
PULCHNT     11/1/2017 17:47   503057701271.00
KNIGHTJ     11/1/2017 22:13   503050726708.00
CACEREB     11/1/2017 16:59   503050719729.00
CONCEPM     11/1/2017 19:33   503050725209.00
HWHITAK     11/1/2017 23:08   93050704897.00
OPOKUGE     11/1/2017 11:11   503040703209.00
NIEMIES     11/1/2017 11:59   503050700514.00
CACEREB     11/1/2017 13:23   503050710931.00
FOSTERV     11/1/2017 20:22   503050715018.00
```

I want to look into the `ctn_id` section of the data frame and perform a test saying : if the 6th character of the `ctn_id` is 7, then display the result.

I have been trying to do this using `sub`, but having the specific element number makes it a bit complicated for me.

Comment: I don't think you need `grepl`, and [`substr`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substr.html) would be more helpful

Comment: how can i find a specific character in substr, in my case i need the sixth character to be 7. so probably substr(test$ctn_id, 6, 6), where 6 and 6 is the start and the end  ??

Comment: Did you read the helpfile? e.g. `substr(x = c('fooba7haz', 'fooba8haz'), start = 6, stop = 6) == "7"`

Comment: Yes, but it's `ctnid`, no underscore. Try `inx <- substr(test$ctnid, 6, 6) == "7"; test[inx, ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grepl` to match any five characters from beginning of string and then the number 7

```
grepl("^.{5}7", df1$ctnid)
df1$ctnid[grepl("^.{5}7", df1$ctnid)]

[1] 503057701271  93050704897
```